# Wireshark not working in promiscuous mode when router is re-started

Tags: wireshark

I am having a problem with Wireshark. I have been able to set my network adaptor in monitor mode and my wireshark in promiscuous/monitor mode. I am able to see the ICMP traffic from my target device to my hooter device which are both on WiFi.

However when I restart the router, I am not able to see the traffic from my target device to my hooter device. Is this because the I need to capture the eapol packets from my target device and my hooter device even after the router is restarted? I am not however stopping my wireshark capture when I restart my router so it should be able to capture the eapol traffic from my target device and my hooter device when I restart my router. Can someone please clarify what I am doing wrong here?

regards,
Rajkumar

Comment: Can you check whether the router uses a different radio channel after a restart?

Comment: I have also tried fixing the router channel to 10 with a secondary channel of 7. At the same time I configured my network adaptor to a channel of 10. But the result is the same.

Comment: Actually there is something called extension channel(not secondary channel). Not sure what is the significance of the extension channel.

Comment: "Extension channel" is for 40 MHz mode (which bonds together two "regular" 20 MHz channels). "Secondary channel" is... no idea what.

Comment: Actually I am using the 2Ghz band. There is no secondary channel. I wrongly used the term Secondary channel. It is actually the extension channel. So since it is 2Ghz band, it may not be using the extension channel.

Comment: And I am using the command "ifconfig wlan0 channel 11" to set the channel of my network adaptor.